# PHP email from header can't get the < >

Tags: php, email

I have a large form sending an email via PHP, and it works if I just use:

```
$headers .= 'From: '.stripslashes($sendfrom). "\r\n" .
```

But this just shows the Name. When I try the following, it breaks the page but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
$headers .= 'From: '.stripslashes($sendfrom) '<'.stripslashes($sendfromEmail)'>' . "\r\n" .
```

I'd like it to output the following format:

```
From: Joe Bloggs <joebloggs@mydomain.com>
```

Could someone help please?

Comment: What you are missing is a dedicated and tested mail library like phpmailer / swiftmailer :)

Comment: Consider using an IDE, which can show you those basic failures instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missing a `.` to concat string

```
$headers .= 'From: '.stripslashes($sendfrom). '<'.stripslashes($sendfromEmail).'>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I could have sworn I'd tried that! It's working now.